# Expression and shape of neighbourhoods in $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, implicit-function-theorem

A neighbourhood in $\mathbb{R^2}$ can be an open ball of the form

$U(a, b) = ${${f(x, y): \sqrt{
(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2} < r}$} for some $r>0 $.

However, it is also possible to have a rectangular neighbourhood of a point ($x_0,y_0$) such as:

($x_0-a,x_0+a$) x ($y_0-b,y_0+b$).

Does it make a difference to use one rather than the other? 
I found the second in the Implicit function theorem, but what does this imply? Why don't we use a general neighbourhood of undefined shape, since we don't know its boundaries?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: one has a circular boundary and one has a rectangular boundary

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thanks! Does it make a difference to use one rather than the pther in the study of a problem? (in particular, I'm dealing with the implicit function theorem)

Comment: If you *defined* a neighborhood as an open ball around the point, then surely the second example is not a neighborhood in that sense.

Comment: Note that both definitions of neighborhoods generate the same topology, so if you are solely using topological properties, it should make no difference

Comment: Thanks to all of you! Now I edited the question to be more specific

Comment: The question is kind of vague. Does it make a difference when you use them *for what*? As Don Thousand has pointed out, it doesn't make a difference topologically, but there are contexts where it might very well make a difference. Also how exactly does this relate to the Implicit function theorem? Is this about its statement or its proof? Have you checked whatever source you are using for its definition of neighborhood? I'm not really sure what you're asking for.

Comment: @Thorgott It is found in the statement of the theorem, it is also present in your previous answer as the starting and ending point of the new mapping. Here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/56k2g.png), however, it ends up being the neighbourhood. Probably this is not clear to me, how this happens

Comment: Note that an interval, such as $(x_0-a,x_0+a)$ in my previous answer, is the same thing as a $1$-dimensional ball. The reason the "rectangle" $(x_0-a,x_0+a)\times(y_0-b,y_0+b)$ pops up in that phrasing of uniqueness is take you take a neighborhood of $x_0$ and $y_0$ each separately and then say that the solution is unique for $x$ and $y$ lying in the respective neighborhoods of $x_0$ and $y_0$ (which is the same as the tuple $(x,y)$ lying in that rectangle). This generalizes to higher dimensions.